# What is too many functions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bestpractice, design-patterns

While reading through on some lightning documentation I came across this piece regarding Anti-Patterns. I have definitely had some helpers which have run the risk of embodying that anti pattern.

How many functions is considered too much in the helper?
Is there some other metric that can be used to ensure your lightning components logic is within acceptable size limits? (I.e. do not require breaking down into smaller components)

Source:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/understanding-javascript-controllers-versus-helpers-lightning-components.html

[image: Comment on Salesforce Website]

Comment: It's not about definitive metrics, that's kind of missing the point. What they're saying is, if you have 1500 functions in your helper, you could probably simplify things by adding some child components, some of which might have their own child components. You should think about the structure of your components, and not ask any one component to do too much.

Comment: It's much like OO programming where when a class gets too complicated dividing into more classes often helps. For Lightning, when a component gets too complicated, dividing into more components often helps. Note the real point is about complexity (i.e. lack of understandability) not the number of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not like there's a reasonable size that you'll reach before Lightning either fails to compile or run out of memory, etc. It's the human factor; really large code is challenging to keep in your mind while you're trying to write/debug something. Each helper should ideally have no more than probably 10-20 methods (most of my helpers usually have less than 5 helper methods, but again, it's subjective). Once you start getting into this situation, you'll start to "feel" like it's getting too complicated, and in most cases, it probably is.

Trust your gut while you're programming and you should probably naturally end up avoiding this anti-pattern. One thing that inexperienced programmers tend to do is to think that they "must be doing it right" despite a nagging sensation in the back of their mind that something's wrong. When you start feeling that way, you should listen to it, and at least review your code to see if perhaps one section could be coded in to a new component.

As a general guideline, try to aim for methods that are about 40 lines or less (in other words, about the amount of code you can fit on the screen at once), and aim for less than 10 methods per helper. This puts you at a maximum of approximately 400 lines per helper. It's okay to go a bit over this, and some complicated components might go over this, but once you hit about 500 lines of code, consider refactoring.

There are a few good reasons to ignore this anti-pattern, but they are rare. For example, some library frameworks might take extensive initialization to complete, or the component can't be broken up in to smaller parts for whatever reason. If you're not sure, try to pretend you're getting a new developer and you have to justify the design to them. If it sounds flimsy or nonsensical, then consider refactoring.

Comment: Do you fancy putting the reusable code in static resources to reduce size of helper?
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/12/lightning-components-code-sharing.html

Comment: @PranayJaiswal In cases where it makes sense, like a shared library for common helper methods (sorting, date manipulation etc), I could be pretty well convinced to do so, but if it's primarily meant to work with Lightning Events or Lightning Components, I'd probably put it into a new component. There's use cases for both.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I've been obeying the 40 line rule for functions (where reasonably possible) for years but wanted to make sure there was not something I was missing in SFDC. I really like the new developer justification piece, like a classic rubber ducky.